# Why is using split resulting in separate array sizes here?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

Suppose I have the following, `String example = "12 8 133 | 7 4 2";` and I want to change it into two equivalently sized arrays, with the intention of later pulling out the individual integers from each.

First, `String[] x = example.split("\\|");` and then

`String[] y = x[0].split("\\D");`

and

`String[] z = x[1].split("\\D");`

Why is it that z is one size larger than y?

In general, what is the recommend way to take a string like the above use a separator and adding the integers into either lists or equivalently sized arrays?

Comment: What's in the arrays? I expect that if you actually look at the arrays, it should be obvious why they have different sizes.

Comment: z is larger because of the space between | and 7

Comment: @immibis a space character is in the arrays. I understand that, but I don't understand why it's included? I've already tried using "\\s+" as Enissay suggested.

Comment: @Legato a space character, or an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are splitting by "not a digit" with `\\D`.  However, the space before the `7` also represents a separator, with the empty string before it.  So, `z` has length `4`.

But, there is a space after `133`.  Why isn't there an empty string after it, so that `y` also has length `4`?  Because the [no-arg `split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) discards trailing empty strings, but not leading empty strings.

To remove the beginning empty string, call `trim()` on the element from `x` before splitting.

```
String[] y = x[0].trim().split("\\D");
String[] z = x[1].trim().split("\\D");
```

Additionally, you may want to use the pattern `"\\D+"`, so one *or more* non-digit characters in a row will count as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String example = "12 8 133 | 7 4 2";
String[] x = example.split("\\s+\\|\\s+");
String[] y = x[0].split("\\s+");
String[] z = x[1].split("\\s+");
```